# Получить значения множественного свойства

Tags: битрикс

**Доброго времени суток**
К товару добавил множественное свойство RELATED_PRODUCT
Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить значения данного множественного свойства, для дальнейшей работы с ними?

Comment: Обратитесь к официальному мануалу по битриксу, там это доступно описывается.

Comment: @ u_mulder - Если вы про это: $VALUES = array();
    $res = CIBlockElement::GetProperty(IKSO_CUSTOM::$IBLOCKS['brands'], $BRAND_ID, "sort", "asc", array("CODE" => "BRAND_CLASS"));
    while ($ob = $res->GetNext())
    {
        $VALUES[] = $ob['VALUE'];
    } то это не работает

Comment: Дело в том что в официальном мануале то что написано, не все работает корректно. По этому обратился сюда, т.к. думал что здесь есть профи своего дела которые могут поделится знаниями =).

Comment: Нет смысла приводить здесь код из мануалов. Надо приводить __свой собственный код__ и объяснять что в нем идет не так как вы ожидаете.

Comment: Коротко говоря - __какой вопрос такой и ответ__.

Comment: @u_mulder - если тебе сложно понять вопрос, то какой смысл тебе сюда заходить в качестве человека который дает ответы? лучше просто промолчи если не можешь дать четкий ответ на поставленный вопрос. а для примера, посмотри как ниже дали ответ, вот это и есть четкий ответ, т.е. ответы такого типа и описывают смысл и задумку данного форума stackoverflow. А тебе я порекомендую на будущее, с начала дать четкий ответ, а потом ниже указать что это есть в документации и указать ссылку. Так будет грамотней.

Comment: "Тыкать" будете вашим одноклассникам.

Comment: @u_mulder - извиняюсь, если обидел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видел комментарии, но не понял, что конкретно не работает. Все правильно сказано, для получения значений из множественного свойства нужно использовать `CIBlockElement::GetProperty`, приведу пример:

```
$iblockID = 1; // ID инфоблока
$elementID = 2; // ID элемента
$arOrder = []; // сортирока
$arFilter = []; // фильтрация, можно по имени NAME => название
$arProductsID = [];
$rsProps = CIBlockElement::GetProperty($iblockID, $elementID, $arOrder, $arFilter);
while($arrProps = $rsProps->Fetch()) {
      $arProductsID[] = $arrProps['VALUE']; // только для примера, фильтр главное правильный был
      print_r($arrProps); // тут в $arrProps в цикле будут возвращаться значения
}

// после уже запрос на получение информации о товарах

$rsProducts = CIBlockElement::GetList([], ['ID' => $arProductsID], false, false, ['NAME']); // в последнем массиве указать какие свойства и поля нужны

while($arrProduct = $rsProducts->Fetch()) {
     print_r($arrProduct); // вот тут уже будут товары
}
```

upd: обновил ответ, добавил пример для получения инфо по товарам

Comment: спасибо. Я получил данные множественного свойства.

Comment: А можете подсказать, как мне теперь получить наименования товаров, их изображения и т.п, информацию, тех товаров которые я подключаю в данное множественное свойство? Задумка такая, что это будут рекомендуемые товары для определенного товара, эти рекомендуемые товары пытаюсь вывести в корзине.

Comment: @Dolphin в `$arrProps['VALUE']` будет ID товара, вот внутри того цикла, который в ответе, собираешь все ID в массив, типа `$arProductIDs[] = $arrProps['VALUE']`, и далее вне цикла уже, ниже `CIBlockElement::GetList([], ['ID' => $arProductIDs])`, остальные параметры уже как по учебнику, в $arSelect добавить нужные свойства товаров, которые нужно получить.

Comment: @Dolphin нет, в цикле запросы к БД делать неправильно, соберешь в цикле ID всех товаров и вне цикла потом одним запросом по эти ID получишь все товары

Comment: Извиняюсь за не внимательность.

Comment: @Dolphin все норм) обновил ответ, примерно так

Comment: @Dolphin пример без учета тонкостей версии и т.п. то есть, там на всякий случай можно проверить, пустой или не пустой массив `ID` шников, еще в фильтр по `ID` добавить параметр `IBLOCK_ID` и т.п.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста а как мне сделать выборку из ассоциативного массива? Например, я в arSelect указал ['NAME'], но на ряду с ['NAME'] есть еще и массив DETAIL_PICTURE, далее в нем есть SRC. Как мне получить еще и данные с данного поля? Т.е. мне нужно не только ИМЯ но еще и картинка.

Comment: @Dolphin `SRC`сразу не получить, в `DETAIL_PICTURE` будет отдаваться `ID` картинки, путь к картинке можно получить с помощью `CFile::getPath`

Comment: пытаюсь получить детальную ссылку, в выборке указываю DETAIL_PAGE_URL, почему то возвращается ссылку такого вида: catalog/avto/#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/

Comment: @Dolphin чтобы ЧПУ и т.п. вещи обрабатывали, в цикле нужно использовать не `->Fetch()`, а `->GetNext()`, еще можно `->GetNextElement()`, но это немного уже другая история